# Parse date dd/MM/yyyy don't work for me with dayjs or date_fns

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, replace, momentjs

I willed replace momentjs by dayjs (or date-fns).

On my example I have this error Invalid Date for a variable:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // date au format dd/MM/yyyy Expected result : 2022-09-23 but I have Invalid Date
    let a = dayjs('23/09/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log('date :' + a);
    
    // date au format MM/dd/yyyy Expected result : Invalid Date but I have 2022-09-23
    let b = dayjs('09/23/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log('date :' + b);
</script>
</head>

</html>
```

Same case with date-fns

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // date au format dd/MM/yyyy Expected result : 2022-09-23 but I have Invalid Date
    let a = dateFns.parse('23/09/2022', 'dd/MM/yyyy', new Date());
    
    // date au format MM/dd/yyyy Expected result : Invalid Date but I have 2022-09-23
    let b = dateFns.parse('09/23/2022', 'dd/MM/yyyy', new Date());
    console.log('date :' + dateFns.format(b, "YYYY-MM-DD"));
</script>
</head>

</html>
```

I thinked in my case the dayjs is quickly replace momentjs with the same syntax. I'm open for another solutions.

I tried dayjs or date-fns, my explanation of my tests are describe with my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, the day.js.org site explain It should be added that:

```
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
dayjs("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY")
```

In my case this is not possible because customParseFormat is not recognized!

I had to write this:

```
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat);
```

This solution came to me when reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335623/1932025)

Here is the functional example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/customParseFormat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat);
            let a = dayjs('23/09/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            console.log('date :' + a);
            
            let b = dayjs('09/23/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            console.log('date :' + b);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I start in js and I imagine that we need to add another library to use the syntax of the site dayjs or date-tns

<sub>*Posted on behalf of question asker.*</sub>